# Speedup by AVX2 and AVX512

Tags: c, avx, avx2, avx512

I am trying to visualize the speedup for incorporating AVX2 and AVX512

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <time.h>
int main()
{
  long i, N = 160000000;
  int * A = (int *)aligned_alloc(sizeof(__m256), sizeof(int) * N);
  int * B = (int *)aligned_alloc(sizeof(__m256), sizeof(int) * N);
  int * C = (int *)aligned_alloc(sizeof(__m256), sizeof(int) * N);

  int * E = (int *)aligned_alloc(sizeof(__m512), sizeof(int) * N);
  int * F = (int *)aligned_alloc(sizeof(__m512), sizeof(int) * N);
  int * G = (int *)aligned_alloc(sizeof(__m512), sizeof(int) * N);

  srand(time(0));

  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
  {
    A[i] = rand();
    B[i] = rand();
    E[i] = rand();
    F[i] = rand();
  }

  double time = omp_get_wtime();
  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
  {
    C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
  }
  time = omp_get_wtime() - time;
  printf("General Time taken %lf\n", time);

  __m256i A_256_VEC, B_256_VEC, C_256_VEC;
  time = omp_get_wtime();
  for(i=0;i<N;i+=8)
  {
    A_256_VEC = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i *)&A[i]);
    B_256_VEC = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i *)&B[i]);
    C_256_VEC = _mm256_add_epi32(A_256_VEC, B_256_VEC);
    _mm256_store_si256((__m256i *)&C[i],C_256_VEC);
  }
  time = omp_get_wtime() - time;
  printf("AVX2 Time taken %lf\n", time);

  free(A);
  free(B);
  free(C);

  __m512i A_512_VEC, B_512_VEC, C_512_VEC;
  time = omp_get_wtime();
  for(i=0;i<N;i+=16)
  {
    A_512_VEC = _mm512_load_si512((__m512i *)&E[i]);
    B_512_VEC = _mm512_load_si512((__m512i *)&F[i]);
    C_512_VEC = _mm512_add_epi32(A_512_VEC, B_512_VEC);
    _mm512_store_si512((__m512i *)&G[i],C_512_VEC);
  }
  time = omp_get_wtime() - time;
  printf("AVX512 Time taken %lf\n", time);

  for(i=0;i<N;i++)
  {
    if(G[i] != E[i] + F[i])
    {
      printf("Not Matched !!!\n");
      break;
    }
  }
  free(E);
  free(F);
  free(G);

  return 1;
}
```

So, the code is distributed in three phase. Three arrays are present. It is just a simple array addition. First we perform it using general loop, then using AVX2 and followed by AVX 512. I am using Intel Xeon 6130 processor.

The code is compiled using the command,

```
gcc -o test.o test.c -mavx512f -fopenmp -mavx2
```

The output is,

```
General Time taken 0.532550
AVX2 Time taken 0.175549
AVX512 Time taken 0.264475
```

Now, the speedup is visible incase of general loop and intrinsic implementations. But the time is increased from AVX2 to AVX512, which therotically should not be.

I have checked individual load, add, store operations. The store operation of AVX512 takes the maximum timings.

Just for the sake of checking if I remove the store operation from both of the code segment, the resultant timings are,

```
General Time taken 0.530248
AVX2 Time taken 0.115234
AVX512 Time taken 0.107062
```

Can anybody throw some light into such a behavior or is it expected ?

********* UPDATE 1 *********

After compiling with -O3 -march=native extensions, the new timings are,

```
General Time taken 0.014887
AVX2 Time taken 0.008072
AVX512 Time taken 0.014630
```

These are with all load, add, store instructions.

********* UPDATE 2 *********

**Test 1 :**

General loop has been modified as follows,

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    //C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
    //G[i] = E[i] + F[i];
}
```

The output is,

```
General Time taken 0.000003
AVX2 Time taken 0.014877
AVX512 Time taken 0.014334
```

Therefore in both the cases page-fault is happening

**Test 2 :**

General loop has been modified as follows,

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    C[i] = A[i] + B[i];
    G[i] = E[i] + F[i];
}
```

So, caching is done in both the cases.

Output is,

```
General Time taken 0.029703
AVX2 Time taken 0.008500
AVX512 Time taken 0.008560
```

**Test 3 :**

A dummy outer loop is added in all of the scenarios and the size of **N** is reduced to **160000**.

```
for(j=0;j<N;j++)
{
    for(i=0;i<N;i+= /* 1 or 8 or 16 */)
    {
         // Code
    }
}
```

Now the output is,

```
General Time taken 6.969532
AVX2 Time taken 0.871133
AVX512 Time taken 0.447317
```

Comment: You forgot to enable optimization!!  Use `-O3 -march=native` to optimize and to tune for your CPU.  (And enable all the ISA extensions it supports.)  Although leaving AVX512VL disabled may stop GCC from being silly and using it unnecessarily.  It could simply be that GCC does something even more inefficient in the AVX512 loop than in the AVX2 loop.

Comment: Your arrays are big enough that initializing A and B right before reading, vs. E and F far ahead of when they'll be read, probably doesn't make a difference.

Comment: If you remove the store operations from those loops, the compiler will simply remove the loops entirely (for they have no effect), Also, if you are profiling without -O2 or -O3, you're not really going to get meaningful results.

Comment: @robthebloke: But the OP compiled *without* optimization so each C statement compiles to a separate block of asm.  e.g. `A_256_VEC = _mm256_load_si256((__m256i *)&A[i]);` will compile to a block that loads the array address and `i` from the stack, uses it for a `vmovdqa` load, then stores the resulting vector to the stack (in the `A_256_VEC` object).  Or possibly with an extra copy because of overhead from not optimizing away intrinsic functions that get inlined.  But yes, after fixing the compile command, the work might be optimized away entirely if the stores are removed.

Comment: @PeterCordes

I have compiled with the -O3 -march=native extension and listed the timings.

Comment: Generic Comment : 

Please if anyone viewing the post have any thought or opinion mention the same in the comment. Voting down a post without going through it does not help in solving the issue.

Comment: Did you forget to enable optimization for your last round of tests?  "General" taking about 8x longer than AVX2 sounds like you left out `-O3`.  Or maybe you used `-O2` or `-O3 -fno-tree-vectorize` to gimp the compiler and force it to make slow scalar code, not even SSE2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your AVX2 test reuses the same array you already wrote with the "general" test.  So it's already page-faulted in.

Your AVX512 test is writing to an array that hasn't yet been touched, and has to pay the cost of those pagefaults in the timed region.  Either dirty it outside the timed region, or just reuse `C[]` again.  Or `mmap(MAP_POPULATE)` also works, wiring up writeable pages.  (For real-world use, lazy page-faults may be better.  Letting the kernel zero a few pages right before you write them might reduce total cost by letting your real writes hit in L1d cache before the kernel's zeroing stores write back to outer caches.)

**Notice that the "general" time (for the auto-vectorized first loop) is almost identical to the "AVX512" time.**  (With `gcc -O3 -march=native`, GCC will auto-vectorize the "general" loop with 256-bit vectors, as per the default tuning of `-mprefer-vector-width=256` for `-march=skylake-avx512`).

Those loops are doing basically the same work: reading 2 initialized arrays and writing a not-yet-touched array, causing page faults.

---

Lower clock speeds from using 512-bit vectors (limiting max turbo) shouldn't lower memory bandwidth much.  (You're going to bottleneck on memory with this 2 read / 1 write access pattern.)  If the uncore (L3 / mesh) slows down to match the fastest core, that could reduce bandwidth some, but it seems that effect is tiny if present at all.

Memory bandwidth for this STREAM-like test should be pretty much the same with 256 vs 512-bit vectors.  If you want to see a measurable speedup from 512-bit vectors for a problem with so little computation per memory bandwidth, you're going to need your arrays to fit in L1d cache and already be hot.  Or possibly L2 cache.    (Use a repeat loop around an inner loop that iterates over the array so it can run long enough for good timing precision).  AVX2 can easily keep up with L3 or memory for this so AVX512 won't help with big arrays unless you're doing more work per vector.

---

There's nothing weird about the asm loops once you enable optimization (https://godbolt.org/z/w4zcrC) so I had to take a closer look at what arrays you were actually writing.

A and B are probably fully evicted from cache even before the AVX2 loop runs (because your `N` is so large; like 662 MiB each for `A`, `B`, and `C`).  But it's still a bit weird to init different arrays for AVX2 vs. AVX512, and not to run any warm-up loop to make sure the CPU's at max turbo.

The "general" time basically acts as a warm-up loop for both clock speed and for page-faulting in the `C[]` array, so the actual time measured for it won't be indicative of memory bandwidth for writing to already-dirty memory.  You might be able to use `perf` to see how much time is spent in the kernel.

Comment: Would `mmap(MAP_LOCKED)` cause it to allocate writable pages instead of the 0-page?

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: yes, I think so, but you can only lock a few pages by default. `ulimit -l` is only 64kiB for non-root on my Arch Linux desktop.  It's not something you really want to do for real use-cases, but sure possibly for microbenchmarking. In real use-cases you often do want lazy page-faults right before writes, I think, especially on Linux where the kernel zeroes the page right then (so the page or handful of pages is/are hot in L1d upon returning to user-space). If the kernel has to zero it sometime, might as well be right before a write. And HW prefetch of other arrays continues(?)

Comment: I just double-checked and `MAP_POPULATE` maps writable pages, not the 0-page. https://wandbox.org/permlink/Vts2vHfn77sv0uAL

Comment: @PeterCordes

Thank you so much for your elaborated answer. It cleared the issue completely.

One curiosity from your answer is that you have mentioned about loading the array in L1d cache or L2 cache. Can you throw some light into it ? Like the procedure or if any online resource available regarding that at your best knowledge.

Comment: @PritamPallab: CPU caches are small, like 32kiB (per core) for L1d.  If you loop over a small array multiple times, all but the first pass will hit in L1d cache (unless you do something else between loops that also touches a bunch of memory).